# Using PyMC3, how could I force a maximum to posterior distribution?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

I am pretty new to bayesian statistics and PyMC3.  I am doing a hierarchical model where the output variable I am trying to predict is a percentage with a maximum of 100%.  My problem is that my posterior distribution includes values greater than 100% which is impossible in my situation.  I configured my Y values as being Normally distributed.  Here is some part of my code, not including the prior definitions to make it briefer.

a = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=mu_a, sd=sigma_a, shape=len(uniqueStores))
b = pm.Normal('Shift1Score', mu=mu_b, sd=sigma_b, shape=len(uniqueStores))
score_est = a[storeIDX] + (b[storeIDX] * audits.Shift1Score.values)

y_like = pm.Normal('y_like', mu=score_est, sd=eps, observed=audits.FinalScore)

I get posterior distributions like thoses:
[image: Posterior]

I was wondering if there some other distribution I could use to force a maximum of 100%. Maybe use a HalfNormal somehow.  The problem with Half Normal is that I can't control the mean, it is at 0.

I was thinking that I could maybe us 1 - audits.FinalScore which would make the scores start from 0 but then I still can't change the mean of that distribution.

Thank you!

Comment: Usually, you specify this sort of thing by defining bounds on parameters, then using the truncated distribution. I know this is possible in Stan, and googling suggests that you can use Bound to do this in pymc3: http://docs.pymc.io/api/bounds.html

Comment: Oh thanks this helps!  But I cant specify observed data in a bounded distribution though which is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

While there are more general approaches to handling bounded parameters like AJK mentioned, in your case you can try some distributions that are designed to describe *probability of probabilities*, such as Beta distribution, or use sigmoid function as your output.